# How to make Banshee/other players recognize a folder as a music player for seamless music synchronization?

Tags: android, banshee, music, sync

I use Webupd8's Go-mtpfs to mount Nexus 4 on Ubuntu 12.10. It mounts the folder in home directory. I use Banshee to manage my music and playlists. Banshee can't recognize the mounted folder as a music player and hence I can't sync my music. Is there a way that I can link or mount Nexus 4 in a way for it be recognized by Banshee as a music player for seamless music synchronization? Banshee FolderSync is broken and doesn't support smart playlists, so, that is a no go.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html

Comment: A solution could be: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/banshee-doesnt-show-android-fix